# Implementing StringLengthAttribute class not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I am trying to implement `StringLengthAttribute` class in order to overwrite `FormatErrorMessage()` method.

However, after adding the new `StringLengthWithCustomErrorMessage` annotation to the property, the unobtrusive validation is missing from the html output:

`data-val-length="Error message"`

I am missing something?

```
public class StringLengthWithCustomErrorMessageAttribute : StringLengthAttribute
{
    public StringLengthWithCustomErrorMessageAttribute(int maximumLength)
        :base(maximumLength)
    {
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format("Value must be between {0} and {1} characters", MinimumLength, MaximumLength);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you just don't pass the error message to the `StringLengthAttribute` like `[StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "Value must be between {2} and {1} characters")]`?

Comment: This worked, thanks. However is still good to know why my attempt didn't worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an adapter for your custom attribute StringLengthWithCustomErrorMessageAttribute

```
protected void Application_Start() {
  DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider
    .RegisterAdapter(typeof(StringLengthWithCustomErrorMessageAttribute), 
    typeof(StringLengthAttributeAdapter));
}
```